# conky: how to refresh the display values?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, conky

why conky duplicates the display after every minute as the picture  [image: desktop conky duplicated display]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a common issue with Conky and graphics.  You can try enabling double buffering:

```
# Use double buffering (reduces flicker, may not work for everyone)
double_buffer yes
```

or fiddling around with the *own_window*, *own_window_type*, and *own_window_transparent* settings.

Comment: they are already defined as:

double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes
text_buffer_size 2048
own_window yes
own_window_type override
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below

Comment: I've gone back to dig into my old .conkyrc configs.  I had this the following, which I think solved these issues for me:

`own_window_type panel`
`own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager`

Comment: windows cannot be maximized over conky !

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by  `own_window_type normal` 

in the file `~/.conky`